# Does every variety contain a smooth subvariety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $X$ be a projective variety (not necessarily irreducible) in $\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{Q}}$. Given any such $X$, does it always contain a smooth subvariety $Y$ and can we say anything about $\dim Y$?

I would greatly appreciate any comments, answers, references. 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends upon your definition of variety. If you, as Hartshorne, think of a variety as a quasi-projective variety, then yes - just take the set of smooth points contained in $X$ (this is a variety in the sense of Harthorne - because the set of singular points is a closed subset). In that case $\dim X_{smooth} = \dim X$.

If however, you think of as a variety as a *closed* subvariety of either affine or projective space, then the answer becomes more boring. Take for example the variety $X= \{ y^2=x^3 \} \subset \mathbb A^2$. This is a singular curve, and the only smooth closed subvarieties contained in it are finite collection of points.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was actually interested in the latter case. In the latter case, is it possible to say something like there exists a smooth closed subvariety $Y$ with $\dim Y = \dim X - 1$?